# Unable to update app from squirrel nuts server

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

So I have setup a squirrel nuts server (https://github.com/GitbookIO/nuts) for my electron app and everything is up and running, but when it checked the feed url for an update, it doesn't find it.

The update-available event never fires.

The feed url is set to:
https://nuts.mywebsite.com/update/platform/version

I have two releases in my github repo, and the first one is installed.

I should note that I have setup the github webhook, so this shouldn't be a cacheing issue. I have confirmed that the releases files are all available to download via the url manually.

I checked the SquirrelSetup.log file and it seems to be hitting the URL, just not getting the update.

> 2016-08-13 23:36:04> CheckForUpdateImpl: Downloading RELEASES file from https://nuts.mywebsite.com/update/win32/0.0.1-alpha
>
> 2016-08-13 23:36:04> FileDownloader: Downloading url: https://nuts.mywebsite.com/update/win32/0.0.1-alpha/RELEASES?id=MyApp&localVersion=0.0.1-alpha&arch=amd64

Contents of /api/versions:

```
[{
    "tag": "0.0.2-alpha",
    "channel": "alpha",
    "notes": "Testing update.",
    "published_at": "2016-08-14T07:58:34.000Z",
    "platforms": [{
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "RELEASES",
        "size": 254,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "RELEASES",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 254,
            "download_count": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:54:30Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:57:30Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.2-alpha/RELEASES"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "32",
        "filename": "My.App.msi",
        "size": 71680000,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "My.App.msi",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 71680000,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:54:30Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:58:32Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.2-alpha/My.App.msi"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-delta.nupkg",
        "size": 3354516,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-delta.nupkg",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 3354516,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:54:30Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:55:32Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.2-alpha/MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-delta.nupkg"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-full.nupkg",
        "size": 73020339,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-full.nupkg",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 73020339,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:54:30Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:56:31Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.2-alpha/MyApp-0.0.2-alpha-full.nupkg"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "MyApp.exe",
        "size": 72183296,
        "content_type": "application/x-msdownload",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyApp.exe",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/x-msdownload",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 72183296,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:54:30Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:57:29Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.2-alpha/MyApp.exe"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "tag": "0.0.1-alpha",
    "channel": "alpha",
    "notes": "Initial release for testing.",
    "published_at": "2016-08-14T07:44:25.000Z",
    "platforms": [{
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "RELEASES",
        "size": 86,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "RELEASES",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 86,
            "download_count": 398,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:40:46Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:43:11Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.1-alpha/RELEASES"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "32",
        "filename": "MyAppSetup.msi",
        "size": 71684096,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyAppSetup.msi",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 71684096,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:40:46Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:41:54Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.1-alpha/MyAppSetup.msi"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "MyApp-0.0.1-alpha-full.nupkg",
        "size": 73019931,
        "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyApp-0.0.1-alpha-full.nupkg",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 73019931,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:40:46Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:44:10Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.1-alpha/MyApp-0.0.1-alpha-full.nupkg"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234567",
        "type": "windows_32",
        "filename": "MyApp.exe",
        "size": 72183296,
        "content_type": "application/x-msdownload",
        "raw": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codephobia/my-app/releases/assets/1234567",
            "id": 1234567,
            "name": "MyApp.exe",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "codephobia",
                "id": 1234567,
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=3",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/codephobia",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/codephobia/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": false
            },
            "content_type": "application/x-msdownload",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 72183296,
            "download_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2016-08-14T07:40:46Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-08-14T07:43:11Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/codephobia/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.1-alpha/MyApp.exe"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `nuts.mywebsite.com/api/versons`

Comment: I added that for you @MarshallOfSound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this was just a simple issue with the SemVer having a "-alpha" on the end. Once removing that and retesting, it works just fine.

Related to issue https://github.com/GitbookIO/nuts/issues/54 which looks like it has been patched in a pull request https://github.com/GitbookIO/nuts/pull/52, but not merged yet.